# Why the `avaiable memory` is less than `total memory`?

Tags: memory, cpu

I usually use the command `free -m` to get the total physical memory capacity. But I found the information is not consistant with the real cpu information. For example, my computer has 8G memory, however `free -m` gives me the information `7.7G`, Can anybody tell me the reason? And how can I get the real memory information `8G`?

By reading `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348007/how-can-i-find-out-the-total-physical-memory-ram-of-my-linux-box-suitable-to-b` I know about the way to get the **total memory** , But I also want to know about what occupies some memory? Is it the bios?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your operating system, you can get a more accurate picture with `cat /proc/meminfo`.

Comment: that's not real memory information. And it's same as the command `free -h`